# Centos 6 iptables

Tags: iptables, ssh, centos

Всем доброго дня. Купил VPS на hostinger.ru, пытаюсь в iptables прописать правило:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/hour --hashlimit-burst 2 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name SSH --hashlimit-htable-expire 60000 -j ACCEPT
```

На что мне валится ошибка **iptables: No chain/target/match by that name**. Сразу говорю, цепочка INPUT есть. Лично у меня падают подозрения на этот отрывок:

```
--hashlimit-name SSH
```

Из документацию прочитал, что hashlimit-name смотри в **/proc/net/ipt_hashlimit/имя_таблицы**, но почему-то в этой сборке CentOS 6 ее в принципе нету на диске. Есть /proc/net, где net это ссылка, которая кидает в **/proc/9586/net**, и там нету ipt_hashlimit.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

uname -r:

```
2.6.32-042stab085.20
```

Comment: Могет у вас модуля нету , он входит в состав xtables-addons-common.

Comment: Попробовал установить xtables-addons-common по этому мануалу http://www.howtoforge.com/xtables-addons-on-centos-6-and-iptables-geoip-filtering. Выдало ошибку на ./configure:...checking Xtables module directory... /lib/xtableschecking kernel version that we will build against... make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab085.20/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.0.0.0.0 in /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab085.20/buildWARNING: That kernel version is not supported....Что можно сделать в этой ситуации?

Comment: надо поставить хедеры ядра отсюда видимоhttp://openvz.org/Download/kernel/rhel6/042stab085.20но я чет не уверен что заработает, этож VZ - не гипервизор, а значит ядро и модули должны быть подключены на хосте, спросите саппорт своего провайдера.

Comment: Спросил у хостера, они не могут установить модули =( жаль, спасибо за ответ

Comment: У Вас ядро OpenVZ виртуалки 2.6.32-042stab085.20На данное ядро можно поставить, но надо иметь полный доступ к сурверу, есть ли у Вас root доступ к серверу?Так как чтоб на ОпенВЗ поставить нужные пакеты надо заходить с основной ноды в имадж вашего куска и доставлять пакеты, по другому у Вас не хватить прав на установку пакетов.

Comment: Дайте вывод команды lsmod

Comment: root к серверу есть

Answer (score 1):

Поидее Вам вот это надо - http://htf.net.ua/xtables_addons_na_centos_6_iptables_geoip_filtraciya

Если ВДС на OpenVZ, то Вам только через прова делать.Если на XEN или VB, то все должно поставиться.

Comment: Это то же самое, что и в моей ссылке, выдает ту же ошибку:checking kernel version that we will build against... make: *** No rule to make target `kernelrelease'.  Stop.0.0.0.0 in /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab085.20/buildWARNING: That kernel version is not officially supported.Видимо, в моей ситуации вопрос не решаем, но, вероятнее всего, ваша ссылка бы помогла. Спасибо

Comment: Дайте вывод команды lsmod

Comment: Вывод пустойhttp://clip2net.com/s/i6XK8J

Comment: У Вас рут доступ к ВПС на данном скрине.А нужен к основному серверу, на котором создана ВПС.